# difference between throw return and break in Maxima

Tags: loops, nested, return, break, maxima

I am very new in Maxima. I need to break from a nested loop and return back to the first one. Here is the code which I have

```
for i:1 while i<= p do (
if i=r then return 
else(
    for j:1 while j<= q do (
        if j=s and X[i][j]#0
        then (
        mult:entier(X[i][j]/vezb),
        X:ratsimp(rowop(X,i,r,mult)),
        return
        )
        else return
    )
)
```

With throw it will do nothing; with break and return it's the same and continues computing without breaking from the nested loop.

Can I ask for an explanation of the differences between throw, break and return on this example?

Answer (score 1):

`return` doesn't mean the same thing in Maxima as it does in other programming languages. It means only to return a value from a `block`; that's not enough for what you need here.

One way to break an inner loop and get a value from the inner loop to the outer loop is to use `throw` and `catch`. Note the use of `throw` to send the value from the inner loop to the outer loop, where `catch` receives the value.

```
(%i6) for i thru 10
      do print ("found j =", catch (for j thru 10
                                    do if i = j then throw (j)));
found j = 1 
found j = 2 
found j = 3 
found j = 4 
found j = 5 
found j = 6 
found j = 7 
found j = 8 
found j = 9 
found j = 10 
(%o6)                                done
```

EDIT: You can use `return` with `block` but then you have to wrap it in another `return`, i.e.: `for i thru 10 do print ("found j =", for j thru 10 do if i = j then return (block (return (j))));`

I'll leave it to you to decide which solution is less ugly ....

Comment: `return` would do the same thing as `throw/catch` here, wouldn't it?  From the Maxima manual:  *The value normally returned by a do statement is the atom done. However, the function return may be used inside the body to exit the do prematurely and give it any desired value.*  `for i thru 10 do print ("found j =", for j thru 10 do if i = j then return (j));` appears to do the same thing as the `throw/catch` version.

Comment: If you have `return(j)` inside `block` (i.e. `for i thru 10 do print ("found j =", for j thru 10 do if i = j then block (return (j)));`) then it won't have the desired effect anymore. If you want to go down that road, it means you have to can either have a return value, or you can use `block` -- I don't think that's really workable. But I have to admit that `throw`/`catch` is kind of ugly too.

Comment: @LassiterRoofingTeam I guess you can write `return(block(return(...)))` -- I've edited my answer to show that. It's still pretty ugly.

Comment: My understanding of the quotation from the manual was that you don't need `block` if you use `return` inside a loop.  `return(block(return(j)))` will cause the loop to return the same value--the current value of j--as just `return(j)`, because `return` can be used without a `block` if it's inside a do loop.  `for i thru 10 do print ("found j =", for j thru 10 do if i = j then return (j));`, when run, has the same output as your new code.

Comment: Right, my point was that `block` is very common in for loops and I was looking for a construct which works with or without a `block` in `for`.

Answer (score 0):

`return` requires an argument.  If you want to return `true`, for example, you need to write `return(true)`.  `return` within a loop stops the iteration and returns the value of its argument as the value of the loop.

The purpose of `break` is to allow you to change the environment (e.g., global variables) in the middle of a computation.

```
(%i1) k : 10;
(%o1)                               10
(%i2) (break(k*10),k*10);
100 

Entering a Maxima break point. Type 'exit;' to resume.
_k : 20;
20
_exit;
(%o2)                               200
```

So `k` was set to 10, and `break(k*10)` evaluated the expression `k*10`, then paused the computation to allow me to change the environment, at which point I set `k : 20` and typed exit to resume the computation, and then Maxima evaluated the next expression `k*10` with respect to the new value of `k`.

`throw` is used with the `catch` function.  `catch(e1,e2,...,en)` evaluates the expressions `e1,e2,...,en`.  If none of these evaluates to a `throw` function, `catch` returns the value of `en`.  If one of these expressions evaluates to a `throw` function, then the value of the `throw` function is returned, and the rest of the expressions are not evaluated.

```
(%i1) h(x) :=  if x < 0 then throw(x) else f(x)$
(%i2) g(l) := catch (map (h, l))$
```

`h(x)` returns `f(x)` for positive `x` and `throw(x)` for negative `x`.  `g(l)` maps `h` over the list `l`, and catches any thrown values.  So if there is no negative integer in a list, `g` returns a list of `f` applied to each integer:

```
(%i3) g([1, 2, 3, 4]);
(%o3)                    [f(1), f(2), f(3), f(4)]
```

And if there is a negative integer in a list, the `g` catches the first such integer and returns it.

```
(%i4) g([1, 2, -3, 4]);
(%o4)                               - 3
```